# promt not working in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I try to get a prompt message. But it doens't work.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm10.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication9.WebForm10" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <h1 id="main-heading">Hello world!</h1>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


 var headingElement = $("#main-heading");
 console.log(headingElement.innerHTML);
 var newHeadingText = prompt("Please provide a new heading:");
 headingElement.innerHTML = newHeadingText;


    });



</script>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So this is the Jquery manner. But the prompt will not be shown.

How change this, that the prompt will be shown?

Thank you

but you say:

Before the  tag, so like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm10.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication9.WebForm10" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>




    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <h1 id="main-heading">Hello world!</h1>



    </div>
    </form>




    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


 var headingElement = $("#main-heading");
 console.log(headingElement.text);
 var newHeadingText = prompt("Please provide a new heading:");
 headingElement.innerHTML = newHeadingText;


    });

        </script>


</body>
</html>
```

but that doesn't work.

Oke, I have it now like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm10.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication9.WebForm10" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1 id="main-heading">Hello world!</h1>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var headingElement = $("#main-heading");
            console.log(headingElement.text());
            var newHeadingText = prompt("Please provide a new heading:");
            headingElement.text(newHeadingText);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But the prompt is still now shown.

Comment: `prompt()` is not jQuery.... just saying..

Comment: How to correct then? Thank you

Comment: Christos already answered :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script should be added before the body closing tag, `</body>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var headingElement = $("#main-heading");
  console.log(headingElement.text());
  var newHeadingText = prompt("Please provide a new heading:");
  headingElement.text(newHeadingText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <h1 id="main-heading">Hello world!</h1>
  </div>
</form>
```

Furthermore, you should use the `text` method. For info about this method, please have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/). There isn't any property called `innerHTML` on a jquery object (`headingElement` is a jquery object, it's not the same as `document.getElementById('main-heading')`, which would return you an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) object, which has a property called `innerHTML`).

Comment: ah. Thank you. Nice

Comment: @LikeToDo did you read the comments above in the answer about the `text` method and `innerHTML` property? As I see you still use the `innerHTML`.

Comment: @LikeToDo do you get any errors? This could be easily spotted by opening developer tools, press F12 if you use Chrome and then go the tab called Console. Do you see any message there? Are you sure that you have loaded the jquery library? Reading again your code, I am almost sure that you have forgotten to add the jquery library. This library should be requested before your scrips is loaded.  So before you starting script tag, `<script>`, you should have something like this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: @LikeToDo Great !